# How to use gulp to minify all the js of angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

So I have installed gulp in my angular project, this is my gulpfile.js at the moment:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var templates = require('gulp-angular-templatecache');
var minifyHTML = require('gulp-minify-html');

// Minify and templateCache your Angular Templates
// Add a 'templates' module dependency to your app:
// var app = angular.module('appname', [ ... , 'templates']);

gulp.task('templates', function () {
  gulp.src([
      './**/*.html',
      '!./node_modules/**'
    ])
    .pipe(minifyHTML({
      quotes: true
    }))
    .pipe(templates('templates.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('tmp'));
});

// Concat and uglify all your JavaScript

gulp.task('default', ['templates'], function() {
  gulp.src([
      './**/*.js',
      '!./public/js/**/*.js',
      '!./node_modules/**',
      '!./gulpfile.js',
      '!./dist/all.js'
    ])
    .pipe(concat('all.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

When I run gulp default, everything succeeds. But how can I notice this exactly? I don't get the feeling that anything has changed, my js files still look the same.

This is my project structure:

[image: Project structure]

Comment: if you just mean knowing when gulp finishes, you can use https://github.com/mikaelbr/gulp-notify to enable a notification when the build completes.

if you mean the files that gulp is creating, look under `dist/`, that's where your files are being minified to

Answer (score 1):

As your gulp configuration specifies, you would have obtained a file named `all.js` inside your `dist/` directory. This is the file that would contain your all *.js files minified code.

You should be including this inside your index.html

Comment: Well when I do this, I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL in all.js, I gues I will not be using gulp then.

Answer (score 0):

Your original js files are untouched. There is template.js under "tmp" folder and all.js under "dist" folder. Those files are minimized.

Answer (score -1):

you can use

> gulp build

that will give you a minified js inside a dist.zip

 more info  [click here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-build)